# Retrieve button value of button pressed

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, powershell, bootstrap-5

I got a question, I´m building a website which can be startete via powershell.
The PowerShell HTML code is this:

```
$proxys = ""
foreach ($email in $ADObj.proxyAddresses){
$proxys += "<button id='$email' name='alias' type='button' class='list-group-item list-group-item-action' data-bs-toggle='modal' data-bs-target='#EditAlias' value='$email' onclick='btnpressforalias();'> $email </button>"
}
```

my HTML code is:

```
[...]
<script>
var btnpressforalias = function () {
let address_type = $(this).value.split(":");
if(address_type[0] == "SMTP") {$('aliastype').val('aliastyp_primary_mail').change();}
if(address_type[0] == "smtp") {$('aliastype').val('aliastyp_alias_mail').change();}
if(address_type[0] == "SIP") {$('aliastype').val('aliastyp_primary_sip').change();}
if(address_type[0] == "sip") {$('aliastype').val('aliastyp_alias_sip').change();}
if(address_type[0] == "x500") {$('aliastype').val('aliastyp_x500').change();}
if(address_type[0] == "notes") {$('aliastype').val('aliastyp_notes').change();}
let address = address_type[1].split("@");
document.getElementById('aliasaddress_local').value = address[0];
};
</script>
[...]
<button id="smtp:test@test.com" name="alias" type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#EditAlias" value="smtp:test@test.com" onclick="btnpressforalias();">smtp:test@test.com</button>
[...]
<div class="input-group">
<select id="aliastyp" name="aliastyp" class="form-select col-sm-2">
<option id="aliastyp_primary_mail" value="SMTP">SMTP</option>
<option id="aliastyp_alias_mail" value="smtp">smtp</option>
<option id="aliastyp_primary_sip" value="SIP">SIP</option>
<option id="aliastyp_alias_sip" value="sip">sip</option>
<option id="aliastyp_x500" value="x500">x500</option>
<option id="aliastyp_notes" value="notes">notes</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="aliasaddress_local" name="aliasaddress_local" class="form-control col-sm-6" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^a-z0-9 .]/gi, '');">
<select class="form-select col-sm-2" id="primarysmtpaddress_accepteddomain" name="primarysmtpaddress_accepteddomain">
<!-- {row_ad} -->
</select>
</div>
```

By button press the modal comes up, but the Selected type nor the text get into the inbox. What I dont see?

I tried serveval different "versions" of the jquery script but nothing helps :(

Comment: You are missing either `#` in this selector `$('aliastype')`

Answer (score 0):

There is many small errors you need to fix before this will work:

1. You need to add `this` to `onclick="btnpressforalias();"`
2. Then you change `btnpressforalias = function()` to `btnpressforalias = function(obj)`, and then use `let address_type = $(obj).val().split(":");`
3. A jQuery object does not have `.value` but instead have `.val()` : `$(obj).value.split(":")` -> `$(obj).val().split(":")`
4. You are missing you id(`#`) selector in `$('aliastype')`
5. You have a type error - You looking for `$('#aliastype')` but your element is called aliastyp.
6. You need to set the value of the select, not the id - `$('aliastype').val('aliastyp_primary_mail')` -> `$('aliastype').val('SMTP')`

Last I would advice you, if possible, not to mix javascript and jQuery.
`$('#aliasaddress_local').val(address[0]);`

**Modified code**

```
var btnpressforalias = function(obj) {
  let address_type = $(obj).val().split(":");
  if (address_type[0] == "SMTP") {
    $('#aliastype').val('SMTP').change();
  }
  if (address_type[0] == "smtp") {
    $('#aliastype').val('smtp').change();
  }
  if (address_type[0] == "SIP") {
    $('#aliastype').val('SIP').change();
  }
  if (address_type[0] == "sip") {
    $('#aliastype').val('sip').change();
  }
  if (address_type[0] == "x500") {
    $('#aliastype').val('x500').change();
  }
  if (address_type[0] == "notes") {
    $('#aliastype').val('notes').change();
  }
  let address = address_type[1].split("@");
  document.getElementById('aliasaddress_local').value = address[0];
};
```

**Demo**

```js
var btnpressforalias = function(obj) {
  let address_type = $(obj).val().split(":");
  if (address_type[0] == "SMTP") {
    $('#aliastype').val('SMTP').change();
  }
  if (address_type[0] == "smtp") {
    $('#aliastype').val('smtp').change();
  }
  if (address_type[0] == "SIP") {
    $('#aliastype').val('SIP').change();
  }
  if (address_type[0] == "sip") {
    $('#aliastype').val('sip').change();
  }
  if (address_type[0] == "x500") {
    $('#aliastype').val('x500').change();
  }
  if (address_type[0] == "notes") {
    $('#aliastype').val('notes').change();
  }
  let address = address_type[1].split("@");
  document.getElementById('aliasaddress_local').value = address[0];
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="smtp:test@test.com" name="alias" type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#EditAlias" value="smtp:test@test.com" onclick="btnpressforalias(this);">smtp:test@test.com</button>

<div class="input-group">
  <select id="aliastype" name="aliastyp" class="form-select col-sm-2">
    <option id="aliastyp_primary_mail" value="SMTP">SMTP</option>
    <option id="aliastyp_alias_mail" value="smtp">smtp</option>
    <option id="aliastyp_primary_sip" value="SIP">SIP</option>
    <option id="aliastyp_alias_sip" value="sip">sip</option>
    <option id="aliastyp_x500" value="x500">x500</option>
    <option id="aliastyp_notes" value="notes">notes</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" id="aliasaddress_local" name="aliasaddress_local" class="form-control col-sm-6" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^a-z0-9 .]/gi, '');">
  <select class="form-select col-sm-2" id="primarysmtpaddress_accepteddomain" name="primarysmtpaddress_accepteddomain">
    <!-- {row_ad} -->
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey, tahnk you very much for your input regards my problem. I could fix the code so far but still no update on the select or textbox in the modal. Is there anything else I need todo?

Comment: Is it maybe, that my boostrap version doesnt support jquery?
I cannot download the js which you declare in the head. I only can use what is on the server. What i have in the head is:
`<script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>`

Comment: @FourK you are already using jquery like in this line `$('#aliastype').val('SMTP').change()`

Comment: Ah sorry, but why it isnt working then? Something is missing so the value gets changed?

Comment: @FourK You need to explain what is not working, your code or the example i've gave you or?

Comment: I got it, i forgot to include the jquery.min.js in the header :(

Answer (score 0):

The answer was the missing include of js. I downloaded and included the newest version and the script worked. Everything is perfect, thanks to @Carsten Løvbo Andersen